# Changing the value of multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the simple question. I have a form with multiple input fields.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the value of all class=*amount* inputs to 10. I've tried the following simple script but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
$(".amount").each(function(){
   this.value = '10';
})
```

Comment: did you add jquery plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want to change the value of all `.amount`, no need to iterate them.

```js
$(".amount").val(10)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code to the following:

```
$(".amount").val(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.amount').val(10);
```

**OR**

```js
$('.amount').each(function(index,element) {

  element.value = 10;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```